# ember-data creating a record with a one-to-many relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create a new record with a associated relationship from the next two models.

```js
App.Kid = DS.Model.extend({
    attribute1: DS.attr("string"),
    parent: DS.belongsTo(parent)
});

App.Parent = DS.Model.extend({
    attribute1: DS.attr("string"),
    kids: DS.hasMany(kid)
});
```

And my route is the following. I'm using also an action handler in my template for save my model with the new values for the attributes through a form.

```js
App.KidRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (id) {
        return this.store.createRecord('kid', {parent: id});
    },
    actions:{
        save: function(){
            this.get('currentModel').save();
        }
    }
});
```

But I'm getting this error.

```
Assertion failed: You can only add a 'parent' record to this relationship
```

I know I'm doing something wrong but the thing is that it works if `parent` is just an attribute and not a belongTo relation. But I don't want this.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Please post your router definition

Comment: I don't think the problem will be here but I'm using `this.resource('kid')` inside my `App.Router.map`.

Answer (score 2):

In that code:

```
this.store.createRecord('kid', {parent: id});
```

The variable id probally is some string, number etc. ember-data expects the model instance, so you will need to load it.

Try to use the following:

```
App.KidRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (id) {
        var route = this;
        return this.store.find('parent', id).then(function(parentModel) {
            return route.store.createRecord('kid', {parent: parentModel});
        });
    },
    actions:{
        save: function(){
            this.get('currentModel').save();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The id is a number indeed and you're right. In fact, I'd also tried exactly your solution but with no results because ember says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'save' of undefined`...

Comment: I simulated your problem here http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/QUJ8j/ and the save method is still present.

Comment: But your simulation is partial because I need to create a record with the associated model like you write above so if I do it with `{parent: parentModel}` I get the `undefined` error. :/

Comment: And the reason is `createRecord` call doesn't create the record although I don't know why.

Comment: Try to use `this.get('controller.model').save()`, inside of the route, maybe could work ...

Comment: Same result unfortunalety.

Comment: No, it's the only error I get, but like I said before it's possible that the problem resides in the creation of the record. I don't know.

Comment: Do you have that project in some github repo? I think that would be the easy way to know what is wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid not because it belongs to a much bigger project. Thanks. Hope anybody else can help.

Comment: How about, in your `save` action, you do: `this.modelFor('kid').save()`

Comment: @bschaeffer `this.modelFor('kid').save()` gives the same effect like `this.currentModel.save()`. But `currentModel` is more fast than `modelFor`, because `modelFor` will lookup for the kid route instance in the container, and retrieve the model. With `currentModel` property, we already have the model instance, so there is not lookup cost.